# Colstore vs Rowstore for in-memory algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, memory, vectorization

I'm familiar with using a column- vs a row-store for how a databases internally persists data to disk. My question is whether, for a dataset is entirely in memory, and there's no storage to disk, if the row- vs column- orientation makes much of a difference?

The things I can think of that may make a difference would be:

- For fields under 8 bytes, it would involve less memory accesses for columns than for rows.
- Compression would also be easier on a column-store regardless of whether in memory or not (seems like a non-issue if not saving back to storage I suppose? does compression ever matter on in-memory operations?)
- Possible to vectorize operations.
- Much, much easier to work with a `struct` on a row-by-row basis of course.

Are both of those accurate, and are there any more? Given this, would there be substantial performance improvements on using an in-memory colstore vs rowstore on a read-only dataset, or just a marginal improvement?

Comment: It entirely depends on the operations you do with your data. Factors of around x1-x100 either way can be expected, depending on how effective the different caching layers are (Cache Lines/L1/L2/L3/TLB).

Comment: Compression is a big deal if you're up against the memory bandwidth limit (which you should be for big datasets on modern CPUs).

Comment: The question seems a bit too generic to me and so hard to answer precisely. I would be great if you can add more information about the *kind of analysis* done, the number of *fields* and the *kind of fields* (int? float? string? complex objects?) and the approximate number of *rows* (5? 50? 5000? 1 million?).

Comment: And for the kind of analysis it also depends on *how* you perform that analysis. Do you first do X for all structs then Y then Z or do you take one struct at a time perform X, Y, and Z for that one and then do the same for the next struct? That might be a trivial change - or require deep refactoring of the code to be efficient

Comment: I assume you've started by abstracting your code's access to the data in question, so that you can experiment with the layout and benchmark all you want, right? Especially benchmark, that's the only way to know for sure, theory only gets you so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm familiar with using a column- vs a row-store for how a databases internally persists data to disk. My question is whether, for a dataset is entirely in memory, and there's no storage to disk, if the row- vs column- orientation makes much of a difference?

A lot depends on the size of the dataset, what the contents of each row are, how you need to search in it, whether you want to add items to or remove items from the dataset, and so on.

There is also the CPU and memory architecture to consider; how big are your caches, what is the size of a cache line, and how intelligent is your CPU's [prefetcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_prefetching).

> For fields under 8 bytes, it would involve less memory accesses for columns than for rows.

Memory is not accessed a register at a time, but rather a [cache line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_entries) at a time. On most contemporary machines, cache lines are 64 bytes.

> Compression would also be easier on a column-store regardless of whether in memory or not

Not really. You can compress/decompress a column even if it is not stored in memory consecutively. It might be *faster* though.

> does compression ever matter on in-memory operations?

That depends. If it's in-memory, then it's likely that compression will reduce performance, but on the other hand, the amount of data that you need to store is smaller, so you will be able to fit more into memory.

> Possible to vectorize operations.

It's only loading/storing to memory that might be slower if data is grouped by rows.

> Much, much easier to work with a struct on a row-by-row basis of course.

It's easy to use a pointer to a `struct` with a row-by-row store, but with C++ you can make classes that hide the fact that data is stored column-by-column. That's a bit more work up front, but might make it as easy as row-by-row once you have set that up.

Also, column-by-column store is often used in the [entity-component-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) pattern, and there are libraries such as [EnTT](https://github.com/skypjack/entt) that make it quite easy to work with.

> Are both of those accurate, and are there any more? Given this, would there be substantial performance improvements on using an in-memory colstore vs rowstore on a read-only dataset, or just a marginal improvement?

Again, it heavily depends on the size of the dataset and how you want to access it. If you frequently use all columns in a row, then row-by-row store is preferred. If you frequently just use one column, and need to access that column of many consecutive rows, then a column-by-column store is best.

Also, there are hybrid solutions possible. You could have one column on its own, and then all the other columns stored in row-by-row fashion.

How you will search in a read-only dataset matters a lot. Is it going to be sorted, or is it more like a hash map? In the former case, you want the index to be as compact as possible, and possibly ordered like a [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) as Alex Guteniev already mentioned. If it's going to be like a hash map, then you probably want row-by-row.

Answer (score 0):

For in-memory arrays, this is called [AoS vs SoA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA) (array of structs vs struct of arrays).

I think the main advantage in SoA for a read-only database is that searches would need to access smaller memory range. This is more cache friendly, less prone to page faults.

The amount of improvement depends on how you use the database. There may be some more significant improvement by using more targetted structure (sorted array, B-tree)

Comment: `[one] advantage in SoA for a read-only database is that searches would need to access [less] memory` single attribute searches - I wreck what brains I currently command estimating the trade-off with multi-attribute ones.